# How to ignore a property from model dynamically while sending response to user?

Tags: json, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I'm implementing a rest service where I am sending my model back to client.

```
eg: return ResponseEntity.ok(responseClass);
ResponseClass is my model here where I am setting all data and sending back to user.
```

I have different services and for all services ResponseClass is the common one.

Lets say in my ResponseClass I have 5 properties(id, name, age, gender, phoneNo).

**Service 1**  getPhoneNo(id)--> Here I don't want to send other properties to user. Because I am setting value to phoneNo only .. but while sending response to user others properties are also displaying to user having null value.

**Service 2** getUserName(id)---> need to send only name property not other properties.

`@JsonIgnore` is not suitable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just return a string for the user phone and username.

Comment: I am not returning a single value to user I have multiple values, but not all.